# Could not find the correct Provider above this Consumer Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application, flutter-provider

I am using `Provider` as the state management tool for my flutter app. Here is my provider configuration.

```
runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [ ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) => AuthenticationProvider(
          AuthenticationService(AuthenticationApi.development()),
        ),
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<AuthenticationProvider, TransactionProvider?>(
        create: null,
        update: (context, authenticationProvider, transactionProvider) {
          return TransactionProvider(
            TransactionService(
              TransactionApi.development(authenticationProvider.token),
            ),
          );
        },
      )
], child: MyApp()));
```

But when I consume the `TransactionProvider` I am getting provider not found error. Here is my build method.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Test'),
        ),
        body: Consumer<TransactionProvider>(
            builder: (context, transactionProvider, child) {
          return Center(
            child: Text('Home'),
          );
        }));
  }
```

Here is the error message.

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<TransactionProvider> above this Consumer<TransactionProvider> Widget
```

Our aim is `TransactionProvider` should get initialized only after the authentication succeeds through `AuthenticationProvider`. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Make provider like that on main.

```
runApp(
              MultiProvider(
            providers: [
              ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => TransactionProvider(TransactionService(
    TransactionApi.development(authenticationProvider.token)
    ));
    )),
            ],
            child: MyApp(),
          ));
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, I have initialized the `TransactionProvider` as `null` in the below section

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<AuthenticationProvider, TransactionProvider?>(
        create: null,
        update: (context, authenticationProvider, transactionProvider) {
          return TransactionProvider(
            TransactionService(
              TransactionApi.development(authenticationProvider.token),
            ),
          );
        },
      )
```

Because of this `Provider` unable to find the correct provider by type. Once I changed like below it is working.

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<AuthenticationProvider, TransactionProvider>(
          create: (BuildContext context) {
        return TransactionProvider(TransactionService(
            TransactionApi.development(
                Provider.of<AuthenticationProvider>(context, listen: false)
                    .token)));
      }, update: (context, authenticationProvider, transactionProvider) {
        return TransactionProvider(TransactionService(
            TransactionApi.development(authenticationProvider.token)));
      })
```

The idea I had initially was `TransactionProvider` should not be initialized before the `AuthenticationProvider` gets initialized. So we initialized as `null` and wrote only update method. But for the code to identify we should initialize. As the initialization and update getting called almost immediately, no issues on accessing the `TransactionProvider`.